# REST Benefits compared to Clustering Stateful

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

We all talk about Scaling of REST easily - we can just add nodes to scale horizontally because there is no state -which means no session replication ,no session affinity and so on.

My question is : Why can't we achieve this scaling even in a Stateful application by having clustering ? Let me also add that my focus is only scaling - I do not bother about failure of a node which would cause loosing of data or session log out etc - and so , let us say, I don't need any session replication /caching.

So, what benefits a Stateless-RESTful application would have compared to a  Stateful-Traditional application which can be after all clustered to aid horizontal scaling?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't that you cannot scale a stateful application, it is that it is much harder and a lot more can go wrong. You have to introduce a lot more communication between all the servers in order to share state. With a stateless design you just add more servers, they don't need to talk to each other or even be aware of each other. Anyone who has ever tried to scale a relational database insuring data consistency among all nodes can testify to the hassle involved.

Comment: Hi Mulhall,thank you for your reply...But should the servers communicate between each other even if I don't want them to share any state information like session?As I stated in my Question - availability is not a constraint I want to solve..

Comment: I don't really follow. If they don't need to share state information what are they communicating with each other? Ideally application servers should not know about each other. This makes your life a lot easier. You can just drop in servers as you need without having to update any of the other servers beyond the load balancer.

Comment: My point was : Servers should share the state information like session so that if one node fails, other nodes in the cluster are free to serve the request for users of 'failed' node without loss of data/transaction. But if my requirement is not to achieve this -  i am fine even if the user is logged out due to crashing of a node -other node can start all afresh..So ,in this case what advantage does REST offer me over stateful?

Comment: Primarily REST allows for systems that last a long time without change to the underlying transport protocols. HTTP is REST, and there hasn't needed to be an update of HTTP in years (REST is not a protocol but a set of architecture constrains, HTTP is a protocol that follows REST constraints). So really when most people ask what does REST give me they mean what does following the HTTP protocol properly give me. It gives you a system that scales and lasts, in the same way the web does. What does evolve is the content types transported over the protocol (eg HTML -> HTML4 -> XHTML -> HTML5).